# Why can't I replace Kidney with aliased Kidney AS "a" in the second line?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM Kidney a
-- JOIN and create the derived table
JOIN (SELECT Age, MAX(BloodPressure) AS MaxBloodPressure FROM Kidney GROUP BY Age) b
-- JOIN on BloodPressure equal to MaxBloodPressure
ON a.BloodPressure = b.MaxBloodPressure
-- Join on Age
AND a.Age = b.Age
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff whats with the "akcjsdl" in the title?

Answer (score 0):

First, the alias is not known in the subquery.  If you wanted that, you would use a CTE (which can be referenced in `FROM` clauses), not a subquery (which is defined in the `FROM` clause but cannot be re-used in one).

In any case, I would recommend using window functions for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT k.*,
             MAX(BloodPressure) OVER (PARTITION BY age) as max_BloodPressure
      FROM Kidney k
     ) k
WHERE BloodPressure = max_BloodPressure;
```